# Using FirewallD as SOCKS server

Tags: centos, firewalld, socks

On CentOS 7, can the FirewallD service be used as a SOCKS server? i.e. if I connect ISP line to server's port #1 and LAN to port #2?
Using Squid allows LAN clients to browse only, but other things such as FTP, POP, etc. require a SOCKS server.

Yes, I am aware of using a proper router / firewall, my question is can the Linux server be used in such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

I think what you're really asking is if you have 2 NICs can you use your Linux system as a NAT proxy for other servers within your network.

This you can do.

For this to function as a SOCKS proxy, you'd have to enlist another piece of software that can act as a SOCKS proxy.

#### Possible SOCKS proxy servers

- https://www.inet.no/dante/ - [shows setting it up](https://spark-in.me/post/vds-socks5-proxy-server)
- http://www.delegate.org/
- http://ss5.sourceforge.net/ - [shows setting it up](https://www.proxyrack.com/how-to-setup-a-socks5-proxy-server-using-ss5-on-centos7/)
- http://socks-relay.sourceforge.net/

**NOTE:** See here for more - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Servers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [firewalld home page](https://firewalld.org/):

> #### Features
>
> - [lots of features, none of which mention SOCKS or proxies]

No.